# Deploying your Ember Js App in Microsoft Azure

Tags: git, azure, ember.js, web-deployment

I have created a simple "Hello World" app in Ember.js. It runs in my local environment. After that, I build my app to deploy to the web host by using the command "ember build --env production".

Then, I use local git for pushing it to the Microsoft Azure. In this case, I have deployed my Ember App by using the local git as a deploying options in Azure.
And hence after in my local cmd, i hit this command "git push origin master", the message says successful, **but when I hit the URL in browser - it says that "You do not have permission to view the directory or page". Please can anybody tell me what is the issue here?**

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps. I am able to successfully run my ember app in Azure with these and my code is in Github.

**Step1:** 
npm install ember-cli-azure-deploy --save-dev -g
azure-deploy init

**Step2:**
Replace deploy.sh with following:

```js
#!/bin/bash

# ----------------------
# KUDU Deployment Script
# Version: {Version}
# ----------------------

# Helpers
# -------

exitWithMessageOnError () {
  if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "An error has occurred during web site deployment."
    echo $1
    exit 1
  fi
}

# Prerequisites
# -------------

# Verify node.js installed
hash node 2>/dev/null
exitWithMessageOnError "Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment."

# Setup
# -----

SCRIPT_DIR="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%\\*}"
SCRIPT_DIR="${SCRIPT_DIR%/*}"
ARTIFACTS=$SCRIPT_DIR/../artifacts
KUDU_SYNC_CMD=${KUDU_SYNC_CMD//\"}

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=$SCRIPT_DIR
fi

if [[ ! -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
  NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=$ARTIFACTS/manifest

  if [[ ! -n "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
    PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH
  fi
fi

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$ARTIFACTS/wwwroot
else
  KUDU_SERVICE=true
fi

if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" ]]; then
  # Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  npm install kudusync -g --silent
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"

  if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SERVICE" ]]; then
    # In case we are running locally this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=kuduSync
  else
    # In case we are running on kudu service this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=$APPDATA/npm/node_modules/kuduSync/bin/kuduSync
  fi
fi

##################################################################################################################################
# Deployment
# ----------

echo Handling react app deployment.

# 1. Install npm packages
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/package.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE"
  echo "Running npm install"
  eval /opt/nodejs/8.1.0/bin/npm install
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"
  echo "Building ember app"
  eval /opt/nodejs/8.1.0/bin/npm run build
  exitWithMessageOnError "ember build failed"
 cd - > /dev/null
fi

# 2. KuduSync
if [[ "$IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT" -ne "1" ]]; then
  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/dist" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"
  exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync failed"
fi

##################################################################################################################################
echo "Finished successfully."
```

**Step3:**

Goto Azure portal
Click create resources
Search for “Web App for Containers”
Click create
Enter app name
Choose service plan etc.
Click Configure container
Ensure image source is selected as Docker Hub and enter image name as prashanthmadi/azure-appservice-nginx:1.13 
[image]

Click ok and create the webapp.

When webapp is created goto application settings and
Update WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE from false to true.
DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME  as prashanthmadi/azure-appservice-nginx:1.13
Always ON to ON
Save changes
[image]

Configure deployment source.Once done, hit browse